# Why did the gopi-s suffer so much after Knowing God so closely?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana

God is worshipped because He is the source of Eternal Bliss. It is accepted in Upanishads and Gita.

The Gopi-s are believed to be in the highest state of God-realisation.

Why did then they suffer so much after being united with God throughout the rest of their lives?

Does any saint or scripture explain this?

Comment: if a woman loves her husband dearly, and he has to be away for 3 months for work, and she suffers due to loneliness during that time, is that really suffering ? even if it is suffering, then on the day the husband gets back, wouldn't her joy be worth the suffering ? some might even say 'absence makes the heart grow fonder'.. it is called 'viraha tapa'

Comment: @ram No such  taapa is explained in the Gita and the Uoanishads and somI asked the scriptural reason of this suffering. God once realised is not expected to go away like husband and there must be some deep spiritual meaning.

Comment: it is mentioned in bhagavatam. the gopis specifically request Krishna that they suffer when he is away from them. that is bhakti. god is their husband.

Comment: @ram that one would write in answer!

Comment: i don't know online sources or text / chapter to cite.